# vba worksheetfunction memory address

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have written a dll which requires a pointer to a function with a given signature, say

```
function func(x as double) as double
...
end function
```

I can write such a function (say Asinh) in vba and pass it with the **AddressOf**... vba method, and it works with no problems.

But Asinh is a function already existing in the Excel object WorksheetFunction, and it looks silly to me to write (many) proxy vba functions just to call existing functions. It would be nicer to pass directly the address of such worksheetfunctions. However:

1. AddressOf does not work for (say) WorksheetFunction.Asinh
2. I can get the address of WorksheetFunction with ObjPtr, but from there I'm not able to go on to the Asinh function address.

A related problem is to reuse a function (with same signature) defined in an external dll, but at least in this case it is possible to resolve it with LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress, sort of

```
function ExternalAddressOf (dllname, funcname) as LongPtr
....
end function
```

Or, in case of own-written dll, to implement a function table and use in vba symbolic constants. However, I'd really like to be able to reuse functions already defined in WorksheetFunction. Need help.